# UDF worker timed out during execution when using javascript udf in BigQuery for tf idf calculation

Tags: javascript, google-bigquery, user-defined-functions, tf-idf

I have tried to implement a query in BigQuery that finds top keywords for a doc from a larger collection of documents using tf-idf scores.

Before calculating the tf-idf score of the keywords, I clean the documents (e.g. removed stop words and punctuations) and then I create 1,2,3and 4-grams out of the documents and then do stemming inside the n-grams.

To perform this cleaning, n-gram creation and stemming I am using javascript libraries and js udf. Here is the example query:

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION nlp_compromise_tokens(str STRING)
RETURNS ARRAY<STRUCT<ngram STRING, count INT64>> LANGUAGE js AS '''
  // creating 1,2,3 and 4 grams using compormise js
  // before that I remove stopwords using .removeStopWords
  // function lent from remove_stop_words.js
  tokens_from_compromise = nlp(str.removeStopWords()).normalize().ngrams({max:4}).data()

  // The stemming function that stems
  // each space separated tokens inside the n-grams
  // I use snowball.babel.js here
  function stems_from_space_separated_string(tokens_string) {
    var stem = snowballFactory.newStemmer('english').stem;
    splitted_tokens = tokens_string.split(" ");
    splitted_stems = splitted_tokens.map(x => stem(x));
    return splitted_stems.join(" ")
  }

  // Returning the n-grams from compromise which are 
  // stemmed internally and at least length of 2
  // alongside the count of the token inside the document
  var ngram_count = tokens_from_compromise.map(function(item) {
    return {
      ngram: stems_from_space_separated_string(item.normal),
      count: item.count
    };
  });
  return ngram_count
'''
OPTIONS (
  library=["gs://fh-bigquery/js/compromise.min.11.14.0.js","gs://syed_mag/js/snowball.babel.js","gs://syed_mag/js/remove_stop_words.js"]);

with doc_table as (
  SELECT 1 id, "A quick brown 20 fox fox fox jumped over the lazy-dog" doc UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, "another 23rd quicker browner fox jumping over Lazier broken! dogs." UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, "This dog is more than two-feet away." #UNION ALL
),
  ngram_table as(
  select
    id,
    doc,
    nlp_compromise_tokens(doc) as compromise_tokens
  from
    doc_table),
n_docs_table as (
  select count(*) as n_docs from ngram_table
),
df_table as (
SELECT
  compromise_token.ngram,
  count(*) as df
FROM
  ngram_table, UNNEST(compromise_tokens) as compromise_token
GROUP BY
  ngram
),

idf_table as(
SELECT
  ngram,
  df,
  n_docs,
  LN((1+n_docs)/(1+df)) + 1 as idf_smooth
FROM
  df_table
CROSS JOIN
  n_docs_table),

tf_idf_table as (  
SELECT
  id,
  doc,
  compromise_token.ngram,
  compromise_token.count as tf,
  idf_table.ngram as idf_ngram,
  idf_table.idf_smooth,
  compromise_token.count * idf_table.idf_smooth as tf_idf
FROM
  ngram_table, UNNEST(compromise_tokens) as compromise_token
JOIN
  idf_table
ON
  compromise_token.ngram = idf_table.ngram)

SELECT
  id,
  ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT(ngram,tf_idf)) as top_keyword,
  doc
FROM(
  SELECT
    id,
    doc,
    ngram,
    tf_idf,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY tf_idf DESC) AS rn
  FROM
    tf_idf_table)
WHERE
  rn < 5
group by
  id,
  doc
```

Here is how the example output looks like:
[image]

There were only three sample handmade rows in this example.

When I try the same code with a little bit larger table with 1000 rows, it again works fine, although taking quite a bit of longer time to finish (around 6 minutes for only 1000 rows). This sample table (1MB) can be [found here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sKIx3DkB-SGt5GxfyhfnOtzNpkCOs01v/view?usp=sharing) in json format.

Now when I try the query on [a larger dataset (159K rows - 155MB)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MQKaxwsTkz3dviWaPR7yyh23XeOF76iP/view?usp=sharing) the query is exhausting after around 30 mins with the following message:

> Errors: User-defined function: UDF worker timed out during execution.;
>   Unexpected abort triggered for worker worker-109498: job_timeout
>   (error code: timeout)

Can I improve my udf functions or the overall query structure to make sure it runs smoothly on even larger datasets (124,783,298 rows - 244GB)?

N.B. I have given proper permission to the js files in the google storage so that these javascrips are accessible by anyone to run the example queries.

Answer (score 0):

BigQuery UDFs are very handy but are not computationally hangry and make your query slow or exhaust resources. See the [doc reference](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) for limitation and best practices. In general, any UDF logic you can convert in **native SQL** will be way faster and use fewer resources.

I would split your analysis into multiple steps saving the result into a new table for each step:

1. Clean the documents (e.g. removed stop words and punctuations)
2. Create 1,2,3and 4-grams out of the documents and then do stemming inside the n-grams.
3. Calculate the score.

Side note: you might be able to run it using multiple CTEs to save the stages instead of saving each step into a native table but I do not know if that will make the query exceed the resource limit.